# How to get the method body of a method in the function at cursor position

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I have a method like this:

```
public void Boo()
{
  Hoo(); 
}
```

I'm trying to write a plugin/addon/extension that when you right click anywhere in `Boo()`, then click a menu option. The code that gets called will traverse through `Hoo()` too. So I'm looking to get the method body of `Hoo()` as a string.

Is this possible?

Basically looking for a way to get the methods being called as children for the current method.

Comment: Will this be different than pressing `alt + f12` (Peek Definition)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx

Comment: Basically we're using code gen. So we need to extract the method body of any methods called in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and there is the functionality that you describe already built-in, but maybe yours is different?

Within the body of a method, you can either <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>, or, right-click and select Peek Definition.